# determine routename, controller, action area in net core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to write a class to determine the next step when navigating through an online journey in a net core mvc app.
I would like this journey to be configurable - allowing the step order to be altered based on some configuration.

I figured the easiest way to do this would be to hold a list of 'steps' which would have the controller and action (possibly area and routename), locate the current step in this, and simply generating a redirect based on whatever is next in the list.

I am having trouble getting all of this. I can get the current controller and action fine, using the `ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]`/`["action"]` with no problem, but getting the routename appears to be a bit trickier.
the RouteData also hold a list of `Routers`, but it is not clear which one of these is the one used for the current request.

is it possible to get the route name? or am I barking up the wrong tree..? or do i need to effectively run the current url back through the MVC routing and grab what I need from that.

we are currently using conventional routing set in the `UseMvc(routes=>{`... method in the startup.. with a number of routes in, currently split between different 'products'.
For instance:

```
UseMvc(routes =>{
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "prod1",
                    template: "product1/{controller=AboutYou}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "prod2",
                    template: "product2/{controller=AboutYou}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: If you use conventional routing (e.g. {controller}/{action}/{id?}), won't you have only one route essentially? Or do you actually have more routes defined?

Comment: we do have multiple routes, see edit. maybe we should use areas instead, but was hoping to reuse certain controllers which existed in more than one 'journey'...

Comment: Or you could make `product1/product2` a route value like `{productId}/{controller=AboutYou}/{action=Index}/{id?}` and then your actions can accept `string productId` as a parameter.

Comment: thanks for the input, I was actually using a simple modelbinder to read the product from the Url. could stick that in a cookie instead and use it to set the route like that..